# How to delete entire row if the cell value of a cell does not begin with a number

Tags: vba, excel

Appreciate your help on below query!

I am looking to have a macro created which will help me to delete entire row if the value in the cell in a column A doesn't begin with a number.

for example if the value in Column A has below :-

```
Column A  
12345    Good
A1234    Delete
D5640    Delete
54689    Good
```

Regards
Simmy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test if the first character `Isnumeric`. Gather rows that don't start with a number using `Union` and delete all in one go.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim rng As Range, unionRng As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For Each rng In .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row) 'Or A2 to skip headers
            If Not IsNumeric(Left$(rng.Value, 1)) Then
                If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, rng)
                Else
                    Set unionRng = rng
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
    If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then unionRng.EntireRow.Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```